# quasar q-uploader batch multiple uploader is only uploading single file to database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I'm using q-uploader to upload multiple images to the database using Axios. however, it keeps only send a single file ...

```
    <q-uploader
                label="select images "
                extensions=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
                @added="file_selected"
                multiple
                style="width: 100%"
              >

 methods: {
  
    file_selected(files) {
      this.selected_file = files;
      this.check_if_document_upload = true;
    },
    async onSubmit() {
      try {
        let formData = new FormData();
 for (let x = 0; x < this.selected_file.length; x++) {
          formData.append("banner_image", this.selected_file[x]);
        }
        formData.append("height", this.height);
        await postService.createModel(formData).then((response) => {
          console.log("this.item", response);
          alert(response);
          // this.$router.push({
          //   name: "Home",
          // });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
```

this is my first time using quasar to develop.

All the responses will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: this problem has been solved

Comment: Comment about problem being solved is worthless. Either provide an answer to your own answer to help users who could encounter same problem in the future, or delete this question all together if it couldn't be useful for anyone (for example if it was caused by a typo)